VirtualBox-Redtat 7.9
I'm using Apple Macbook and I have VirtualBox in it. within my Virtual Box I have RedHat 7.9
I need to make a USB drive that i'm connecting into my MacBook visible into redhat. what is the steps please?
Note: I'm using redhat server so I have only terminal to use.
once I can see the use into redhat, I can drive the rest to mount etc....
Thank you.
I have tried many things within the VirtualBox, but looks like i'm not doing it correctly.

You assign the USB device to the RedHat VM using the VirtualBox control panel. The RedHat VM needs no specific configuration for this process.

Hmm....don't you have to install the Virtaulbox extensions to to this?

Correct, I have installed the extension, but it doesn’t work.
I have watched a lot of useful videos of you tube and searched on google, couldn’t found anything for RedHat. I know this shouldn’t be something hard. I’m missing something.
Also, as soon as I run RedHat 7.9 or 8.9 the OS telling me “ can’t read usb device…..”. I can’t see it within the OS either using blkid or fdisk-l.
